# shiny: Reactive UI

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a reactive UI in my shiny app. I would like that if the user select as option "Continue" No option appears in the UI and if the user selects Decrease, then the UI shows a radiogroup with my options.
So far I know how to update the values of the radiogroup but I don't know how to be able to have a UI without the radiogroup "int_dist".

```
      # UI ----------------------------------------------------------

      radioGroupButtons(inputId="radio_group1", 
                        label=tags$i("Social Distance"), 
                        choices=c("Continue" = "cont","Decrease" = "dec")),
      
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "int_dist",
        choices =     c("30%" = "30", "40%" = "40", "50%" = "50"),
        label = "Options"
      ),
      # SERVER ----------------------------------------------------------
    observe({
      option<- input$radio_group1
    
      switch(option,
           "cont" = {
            NO OPTIONS
              
           },
           "dec" = {
               updateRadioButtons(
                   session = session, inputId = "int_dist",
                   choices =     c("30%" = "30", "40%" = "40", "50%" = "50"),
                   label = "Option"                   
                   )
           },
           
    )
})
```

Comment: Have a look at `shinyJS::hide`

Comment: Use conditionalPanel in ui or renderUI with conditions on the server side.

Comment: Can you share the complete app code so that this post becomes reproducible?